# Does an Equivalence Relation Cover the Entire Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm currently at the beginning of studying Set Theory.
We've studied the basic concepts among them- the equivalence relation.
The question:

Assuming we have a non empty set $A$ and an equivalence relation $E$ on $A$.

The definition of a relation is a set of ordered pairs so the relation is a **subset** of $A\times A$. By definition of subset, the relation's members must be in $A\times A$ but **not** every member of $A\times A$ must be in the relation.

So if we go back to the specific example: not every ordered pair of $A\times A$ must be part of the relation group.
This rule, for my understanding is applying to the equivalence relation $E$: there's a member of $A\times A$, called $(x,y)$, which is **not** a member of the relation $E$.

If we go along- $(x,y)$ doesn't have an **equivalence class**- because it is not part of the relation. Therefore not all members of $A\times A$ are part of an equivalence class.

I guess that i'm wrong somewhere on the way and i'm missing something.
what is it?

Thank you in advance,
Yaron

Comment: Nothing wrong with declaring that every element is equivalent to every other element.  Easy to check that this defines an equivalence relation (albeit not a terribly interesting one) and in this case (and only in this case) every element in $A\times A$is in $E$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Does that mean that (x,y) has an equivalence class or not?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking (perhaps that's why my answer wasn't clear).  I thought you were asking if the definition of an equivalence relation on a set $A$ required that there was a pair $(x,y)\in A\times A$ which was not in $E$.  My answer was that the definition does not require this.  If this was not your question, can you clarify what was?

Comment: @YaronScherf A set is a subset of itself. Specifically, a relation is a subset $R$ of $A\times A$, but we can choose $R=A\times A$, since $A\times A\subseteq A\times A$. Also, an equivalence class can have only one element; however, equivalence classes are considered on the set $A$, not on the product $A\times A$: therefore, you can ask "What is the equivalence class of $x$?" but not "What is the equivalence class of $(x, y)$?.

Comment: Perhaps you are unclear on what an equivalence relation is.  It is defined on $A$, not on $A\times A$.  The pairs one looks at in $A\times A$ are those pairs $(x,y)\in A\times A$ such that $x\sim_E y$.  That can be a very useful way to describe an equivalence relation.  Typically, not all pairs $(x,y)\in A\times A$ belong to E$ because not all elements of $A$ are equivalent to all the others.

Comment: @lulu you did get part of what I've asked. looking at your 2nd comment: so lets assume that (x,y) is not part of AxA. if so- does that mean that (x,y) is not part of any equivalence class? (because it is not part of the relation)

Comment: There are no equivalence classes on $A\times A$, so it doesn't make sense to ask if $(x,y)$ is in one or not.  Saying that $(x,y)\notin E$ just means that $x$ is not equivalent to $y$ under $E$.

Comment: ok so let's assume that there's another pair (a,b) which is part of E, now that means that there's an equivalence class of the relation E, and for now only one exist. Does (x,y) again has to be part of some equivalence class or not?

Comment: Really, the equivalence relation is defined on $A$, not on $A\times A$.  Saying that $(a,b)\in E$ is the same as saying $a\sim_E b$ which is the same as saying that $a$ and $b$ are in the same equivalence class under $E$.  If $(x,y)\notin E$ then all you know is that $x$ and $y$ live in different equivalence classes.

Comment: As an example, let $A$ be the integers, $\mathbb Z$, and let $E$ be the equivalence relation defined by parity.  That is to say, $m\sim_E n$ if either both are odd or if both are even.  Thus, $(2,16)\in E$ and $(33,-197)\in E$ but $(2,3)\notin E$.

Comment: so does (x,y) must live in some different equivalence class? even if no other equivalence class is defined?

Comment: No matter how many times you ask the same question, the answer will be the same.  No pair $(x,y)$ is in an equivalence class.  We write $(x,y)\in E$ to indicate that $x\sim_E y$ which is the same as saying that $x$ and $y$ are in the same equivalence class.  But $(x,y)$ is not in any equivalence class because there is no equivalence relation defined on $A\times A$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $E$ is a relation *on $A$*, rather than on $A\times A$. This means that we are concerned with relations between two elements of $A$.

While you're absolutely correct, and while the equivalence relation $E$ could be a proper subset of $A\times A$, the equivalence classes—or the partition they induce—are subsets of $A$.

So stating that $(x,y)\notin E$ will simply tell you that the equivalence classes of $x$ and $y$ are disjoint.

But to answer your main concern about covering, if $E$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, then $E$ is reflexive (on $A$), and therefore for every $a\in A$, $(a,a)\in E$. So indeed there will be an equivalence class which includes $a$.